# Is nilpotent cone lci?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective manifold such that $T^*X$ carries a algebraically completely integrable system with the moment map $\mu: T^*X \to \mathbb{C}^n$, where $n$ is the dimension of $X$. Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two irreducible component of $\mu^{-1}(0)$ different from the component corresponding to the zero section of $T^*X$. If $\mu^{-1}(0)$ is locally complete intersection (lci) then by Hartshorne's  connectedness theorem is will be of pure co-dimension one.

Question: (1) Is $\mu^{-1}(0)$  lci ?

(2) If not then what is the dimension of $X_1 \cap X_2$ ?

Comment: $\mu ^{-1}(0)$ is even *globally* a complete intersection, given by $\mu ^*z_1=\ldots =\mu ^*z_n=0$.